# ViewBinding - access button in layout resulting in unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm going through learning Android development with Kotlin and ran into an issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

When running build I get the following error:

> Code\DiceRoller\app\src\main\java\com\example\diceroller\MainActivity.kt:
> (16, 34): Unresolved reference: rollButto

This is my MainActivity.kt code:

```
package com.example.diceroller

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.diceroller.databinding.DiceRollerMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: DiceRollerMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DiceRollerMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        val rollButton = binding.rollButton
//        this.binding.rollButton.setOnClickListener {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//        }
    }
}
```

Everything works up until trying to access the roll button where it produces a reference error even though it comes up in autocomplete. I've also tried accessing another element and it produces the same error.

This is my xml file (dice_roller_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:andriod="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.andriod.com/tools"
    andriod:layout_height="wrap_content"
    andriod:layout_width="match_parent"
    andriod:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    andriod:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        andriod:id="@+id/name"
        andriod:layout_width="wrap_content"
        andriod:layout_height="wrap_content"
        andriod:text="1"
        andriod:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        andriod:textSize="30sp"/>
    
    <Button
        andriod:id="@+id/roll_button"
        andriod:layout_width="wrap_content"
        andriod:layout_height="wrap_content"
        andriod:text="@string/ButtonRoll"
        andriod:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and I made sure to turn on viewbinding in gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.diceroller"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Has anyone had this issue? I've tried searching for this issue here and on google but cannot find anyone with a similar issue to me.

Edit:

I have gone through the binding class that is generated and looks like the button and text view that is defined in the xml does not have code generated

```
// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!
package com.example.diceroller.databinding;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import com.example.diceroller.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;

public final class DiceRollerMainBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final LinearLayout rootView;

  private DiceRollerMainBinding(@NonNull LinearLayout rootView) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public LinearLayout getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static DiceRollerMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static DiceRollerMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dice_roller_main, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static DiceRollerMainBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    if (rootView == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("rootView");
    }

    return new DiceRollerMainBinding((LinearLayout) rootView);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your XML layout file name?

Comment: dice_roller_main.xml

Comment: It seems your code is ok, Try to change your XML file name to activity_main. xml and access like ActivityMainBinding. it just for a simple try.

Comment: tried that, got the same result.

Comment: can you do something like this  binding?.rollButton while accessing. not sure but sometimes nullable operator is needed to access exact properties.

Comment: Sorry im confused, what do you want me to try?

Comment: Spelling: andr**io**d ?

Comment: Yeah that was it, haha. thanks Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is on your xml file. For data binding, you have to wrap your elements inside of a `layout` component.
Your xml file should look like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.andriod.com/tools">
    <LinearLayout 
        andriod:layout_height="wrap_content"
        andriod:layout_width="match_parent"
        andriod:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        andriod:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    
        <TextView
            andriod:id="@+id/name"
            andriod:layout_width="wrap_content"
            andriod:layout_height="wrap_content"
            andriod:text="1"
            andriod:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            andriod:textSize="30sp"/>
    
        <Button
            andriod:id="@+id/roll_button"
            andriod:layout_width="wrap_content"
            andriod:layout_height="wrap_content"
            andriod:text="@string/ButtonRoll"
            andriod:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: this is for view binding which is different to data binding from what i understand.